# Assigning a new task to a thread after the thread completes in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stdthread

I have the following code in C++. The code is from `C++ Concurrency In Action: Practical Multithreading`

```
void do_work(unsigned id);

void f() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(do_work, i));
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
}
```

Suppose that threads[0] has completed processing and returns a value. I still have more files to process and would now like to assign this new file to a thread that is complete. How can I achieve this behavior in C++ ? Or must I destroy the thread and now create a new one upon thread completion ? But then how do I check if any of these threads have completed ?

Comment: Lookup upon thread pool implementations. You'll need one more level of indirection how the workload is passed.

Comment: You will need to have a way to pass work to your threads (via a queue or other means).  This is significantly different that what you've shown.  This would be a good use case for a proactor, like `boost::asio`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a basic implementation of what Sam Varshavchik has explained.

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/ARbq5O)**

The reason why I've added a `local_queue` is to make sure our `m_Mutex` is unlocked right away. If you remove it the thread that calls `push_task` can potentially block.

The destructor calls `stop()` which sets `m_Running` to `false`, notifies the thread about it, and waits for it to finish processing all remaining tasks.

If the worker class dies, the thread dies too, which is good.

My example only creates 3 threads and 5 tasks per thread `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, mainly to make sure all the output is shown in **ideone**, but I've tested it with 10 threads and 5000 tasks per thread and it ran fine.

The `do_work` function has two lines that you can uncomment if you want the output stream to be properly synchronized. **This class has multi-thread support.**

You can `stop()` and re`start()` the thread as many times as you like

```
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker(bool start) : m_Running(start) { if (start) private_start(); }
    Worker() : m_Running(false) { }
    ~Worker() { stop(); }

    template<typename... Args>
    void push_task(Args&&... args)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            m_Queue.push_back(std::bind(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

        m_Condition.notify_all();
    }

    void start()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            if (m_Running == true) return;
            m_Running = true;
        }

        private_start();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
            if (m_Running == false) return;
            m_Running = false;
        }

        m_Condition.notify_all();
        m_Thread.join();
    }

private:
    void private_start()
    {
        m_Thread = std::thread([this]
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                decltype(m_Queue) local_queue;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
                    m_Condition.wait(lk, [&] { return !m_Queue.empty() + !m_Running; });

                    if (!m_Running)
                    {
                        for (auto& func : m_Queue)
                            func();

                        m_Queue.clear();
                        return;
                    }

                    std::swap(m_Queue, local_queue);
                }

                for (auto& func : local_queue)
                    func();
            }
        });
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable m_Condition;
    std::list<std::function<void()>> m_Queue;
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    std::thread m_Thread;
    bool m_Running = false;
};

void do_work(unsigned id)
{
    //static std::mutex cout_mutex;
    //std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    {
        Worker workers[3];
        int counter = 0;

        for (auto& worker : workers)
            worker.start();

        for (auto& worker : workers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                worker.push_task(do_work, ++counter + i);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "finish" << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to "How can I achieve this behavior in C++" is, simply, write the code to do it. The first step, which you've identified yourself is "how do I check if any of these threads have completed".

There are several basic approaches. But they all boil down to the same thing: instead of letting each thread simply go away, before each thread terminates it notifies the parent process that it's done.

For starters, each thread should know which thread it is. In your example, all threads are placed in a `std::vector`, and they are identified by the vector's index. That's not the only way to do it. There are other ways to shepherd all the threads, but for the purpose of the answer, this will do.

Then, each thread needs to know what index it is, by passing the thread index number as a thread parameter. Which your code already does. Wonderful.

Now, to simply close the end of the loop: you just need to instantiate a `std::mutex`, with a `std::condition_variable`, that's protecting a `std::queue`, or a `std::list`. Or, perhaps, a `std::set` of integers. You are free to decide which container is best for you.

Then, before each thread terminates, it:

- locks the mutex.
- puts its thread index into the container.
- signals the condition variable.
- unlocks the mutex, and then it immediately returns, terminating this thread.

Then, the parent thread, which started all the threads:

- locks the mutex
- checks if the queue/set/whatever is empty. If it is, it waits on the condition variable, until it's not.
- removes the thread index from the queue/set/whatever, and joins that thread. That thread has just terminated. Now you know which thread was terminated, and can do whatever you want with that information.
- after its done handling or restarting the thread, it checks again, if the queue is empty.